# React global SCSS: class styling not working

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, selector, next.js

I am using React with SASS.

For my components, I am using modular CSS, however, in my `Layout.js` file, I want to use a `main.scss` file.

My `main.scss`file is working as when I add style to selectors such as `body {}` or `p {}`, they style these elements. It's the styles for classes that aren't seeming to come through. For instance, in my `global.scss` file, I have the following css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.marginsContainer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

The `body` is working. The `.mainContainer` isn't.

I am trying to use .mainContainer in my Layout.js file, like so

```
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Head from 'next/head';
import '../global-styles/main.scss';

const Layout = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>Practise Site</title>
    </Head>
    <Navbar />
    <div className="marginsContainer">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Layout;
```

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using css-modules?

In that case, css-modules adds a hash at the end of the class name. You can avoid it by switching to the global scope for your class.

```
:global {
  .marginsContainer {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 100px;
  }
}
```

A better solution is to use the class name with the hash, by importing the stylesheet like this.

```
import styles from '../global-styles/main.scss';
```

And setting the class name like this.

```
<div className={styles.marginsContainer}>
```

Comment: Perfect! The first snippet is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Good point with the `:global`. It's needed if `cssModules` are set to true in the `next.config.js` file. I've created the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-night-upb6d) to test the styling.